# How to write NUnit test for dependency injection service .net core

Tags: nunit, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a service class with some injected services. It's dealing with my Azure storage requests. I need to write NUnit tests for that class. 
 I'm new to NUnit and I'm struggling with making the object of that my AzureService.cs

Below AzureService.cs. I have used some injected services

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JohnMorris.Plugin.Image.Upload.Azure.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Nop.Core.Caching;
using Nop.Core.Configuration;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Media;
using Nop.Services.Logging;

namespace JohnMorris.Plugin.Image.Upload.Azure.Services
{
    public class AzureService : IAzureService
    {

        #region Constants

        private const string THUMB_EXISTS_KEY = "Nop.azure.thumb.exists-{0}";
        private const string THUMBS_PATTERN_KEY = "Nop.azure.thumb";

        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private static CloudBlobContainer _container;
        private readonly IStaticCacheManager _cacheManager;
        private readonly MediaSettings _mediaSettings;
        private readonly NopConfig _config;

        #endregion

        #region
        public AzureService(IStaticCacheManager cacheManager, MediaSettings mediaSettings, NopConfig config, ILogger logger)
        {
            this._cacheManager = cacheManager;
            this._mediaSettings = mediaSettings;
            this._config = config;
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        #endregion


        #region Utilities
        public string GetAzureStorageUrl()
        {
            return $"{_config.AzureBlobStorageEndPoint}{_config.AzureBlobStorageContainerName}";
        }

        public virtual async Task DeleteFileAsync(string prefix)
        {
            try
            {
                BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
                do
                {                    
                    var resultSegment = await _container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, true, BlobListingDetails.All, null, continuationToken, null, null);

                   await Task.WhenAll(resultSegment.Results.Select(blobItem => ((CloudBlockBlob)blobItem).DeleteAsync()));

                    //get the continuation token.
                    continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
                }
                while (continuationToken != null);

                _cacheManager.RemoveByPrefix(THUMBS_PATTERN_KEY);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Azure file delete error", e);
            }
        }


        public virtual async Task<bool> CheckFileExistsAsync(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var key = string.Format(THUMB_EXISTS_KEY, filePath);
                return await _cacheManager.Get(key, async () =>
                {
                    //GetBlockBlobReference doesn't need to be async since it doesn't contact the server yet
                    var blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);

                    return await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
                });
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }

        public virtual async Task SaveFileAsync(string filePath, string mimeType, byte[] binary)
        {
            try
            {
                var blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType))
                    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = mimeType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_mediaSettings.AzureCacheControlHeader))
                    blockBlob.Properties.CacheControl = _mediaSettings.AzureCacheControlHeader;

                await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(binary, 0, binary.Length);

                _cacheManager.RemoveByPrefix(THUMBS_PATTERN_KEY);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Azure file upload error", e);
            }
        }

        public virtual byte[] LoadFileFromAzure(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);
                if (blob.ExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                {
                    blob.FetchAttributesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    var bytes = new byte[blob.Properties.Length];
                    blob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    return bytes;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return new byte[0];
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is my test class below, I need to create new AzureService(); from my service class. But in my AzureService constructor, I'm injecting some service

```
using JohnMorris.Plugin.Image.Upload.Azure.Services;
using Nop.Core.Caching;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Media;
using Nop.Services.Tests;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace JohnMorris.Plugin.Image.Upload.Azure.Test
{
    public class AzureServiceTest 
    {
        private AzureService _azureService;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
               _azureService = new AzureService( cacheManager,  mediaSettings,  config,  logger);
        }      

        [Test]
        public void App_settings_has_azure_connection_details()
        {
           var url= _azureService.GetAzureStorageUrl();
            Assert.IsNotNull(url);
            Assert.IsNotEmpty(url);
        }

       [Test]
       public void Check_File_Exists_Async_test(){
           //To Do
       }

       [Test]
       public void Save_File_Async_Test()(){
           //To Do
       }

       [Test]
       public void Load_File_From_Azure_Test(){
           //To Do
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is, what exactly do you want to test? If you want to test if `NopConfig` is properly reading values from AppSettings, then you do not have to test `AzureService` at all.

If you want to test that `GetAzureStorageUrl` method is working correctly, then you should mock your `NopConfig` dependency and focus on testing only `AzureService` methods like this:

```cs
using Moq;
using Nop.Core.Configuration;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NopTest
{
    public class AzureService
    {
        private readonly NopConfig _config;

        public AzureService(NopConfig config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public string GetAzureStorageUrl()
        {
            return $"{_config.AzureBlobStorageEndPoint}{_config.AzureBlobStorageContainerName}";
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class NopTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void GetStorageUrlTest()
        {
            Mock<NopConfig> nopConfigMock = new Mock<NopConfig>();

            nopConfigMock.Setup(x => x.AzureBlobStorageEndPoint).Returns("https://www.example.com/");
            nopConfigMock.Setup(x => x.AzureBlobStorageContainerName).Returns("containername");

            AzureService azureService = new AzureService(nopConfigMock.Object);

            string azureStorageUrl = azureService.GetAzureStorageUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual("https://www.example.com/containername", azureStorageUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: App_settings_has_azure_connection_details() is just a test query. I edited my question with more detils